# review of a submitted paper

Tags: publications

I submitted a paper in april 2017 to the POP Journal, it took 18 days to secure a reviewer. After about 24 days the status said that *review has been received* and thereafter it said *awaiting editor* response.

Soon the status went again to *securing reviewers*. this time the reviewer was secured in about 23 days. It has been almost a month and it still shows *review under process*, generally the POP journal is fast. I don't know what I should do?

Comment: I don't know the journal "POP." In my experience, the journal process should be measured in months, not days. So you should just be patient.

Comment: @Thomas  perhaps  Propagation of Ornemental Plants  http://www.journal-pop.org/ ?

Comment: It seems to me that the first reviewer provided a report that the editor found inadequate, so your paper was sent to another reviewer in hopes of getting a more useful report. The need for a second review slows down the process.  So I agree with "just be patient."

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate. The timescales of the journal in the other question are different but the question is the same.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, there's only one thing you can do: wait.

We've all had to wait longer than we'd like for reviews, and there are any number of possibilities as to why the paper may have had to be rereviewed (e.g. made it past the first round, a conflict was discovered that wasn't previously disclosed, etc.)

If any acceptance decisions get announced and you are never informed of a decision, THEN you may want to get in touch with the editor.

Comment: The last paragraph seems like it only applies to conferences, while the question is about a journal submission.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I was hoping to have my answer be general enough to apply to either situation, but you're correct. I'll update for clarity.